# Objects gets big when dragged around Unity C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have problem when I run this script on some gameobject and I drag it around it gets really big by somehow changing the z positon

```
public class Draggable : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler
{
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, 0);
    }
}
```

Before http://prnt.sc/c2e7t7

After http://prnt.sc/c2e7wb

Even if I attach it to brand new `Image` object for example it always resizes it to this exact Z value -708.4954

**Update** Added small sample project where the problem still occurs : http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=65691163815194240868

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's likely because the Z axis is changing when you did `transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);`, You should store that to a temporary value then change `z` value to `0` before assigning it back to your Object's position.

```
public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    Vector3 noZValue = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    noZValue.z = 0;
    transform.position = noZValue;
}
```

If this does not solve the problem then you are are modifying the Object scale or pos from another code and you should as well show that part of code. For your information, the Object is not actually scaling with that code. It is moving closer to the camera making it look big.

**EDIT**:

The code in your question is a way to move Sprites/Sprite Renderer not UI components such as Image, Button, RawImage....

This should move your UI when your UI Canvas is in **Screen Space - Camera** Mode:

```
public class Draggable : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler
{
    public Canvas parentCanvas;
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Vector2 movePos;
        RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(parentCanvas.transform as RectTransform, eventData.position, parentCanvas.worldCamera, out movePos);
        transform.position = parentCanvas.transform.TransformPoint(movePos);
    }
}
```

If you try this, you will realize that when you click on the image, the image will jump to the click position. You need to add offset pos when moving the image to fix this. Just get the mouse pos when the mouse button is down. Use that to add to the current mouse pos when dragging. This can be done by implementing `IBeginDragHandler` and  using the `OnBeginDrag` function.

Complete UI Image move with offset:

```
public class Draggable : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IBeginDragHandler
{
    public Canvas parentCanvas;
    Vector3 Offset = Vector3.zero;


    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Vector2 pos;
        RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(parentCanvas.transform as RectTransform, eventData.position, parentCanvas.worldCamera, out pos);
        Offset = transform.position - parentCanvas.transform.TransformPoint(pos);
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Vector2 movePos;
        RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(parentCanvas.transform as RectTransform, eventData.position, parentCanvas.worldCamera, out movePos);
        transform.position = parentCanvas.transform.TransformPoint(movePos) + Offset;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing is changing the objects scale or position because I just created a completely new unity project added a simple `Image` object to and also added only this script, and it does absolutely the same thing. If it matters that's my canvas http://prntscr.com/c2eiz3

Comment: I can't tell what else is going on. Zip that simple project then provide a link to it here. I will take a look.

Comment: I will post it in the question.

Comment: That's fine. Will let you know I found

Comment: Did you found out anything ?

Comment: Check the Updated answer. That should work with your current Canvas  camera mode. Please read everything from EDIT down to see what I did.

Answer (score 0):

@OP
I believe the problem may be that your setting position.z to 0 but position.z in your case equals -708.4954 in localPosition.z

To test, Debug.Log(position.z) to see if that is actually zero or set localPosition.z to zero instead of position.

For GUI objects, the position in inspector will ALWAYS be localPosition because they are forced children of a canvas.